# HTML auto spacing between text

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, nav, spacing

I realize this has probably been answered before, and if so, please direct me to another page.

I have a menu bar that goes horizontally across my page. I have several links and I want spacing so the links will fill the width of the nav.

**CSS:**

```
nav {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="menu">
    <a id="home" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a id="link" href="link.html">Link</a>
    <a id="another" href="really.html">Another</a>
    <a id="lalala" href="stupidcode.html">Lalala</a>
    <a id="oneMore" href="example.html">One More</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please show us any applicable HTML as well. A good place to start is to show what the `nav` contains.

Comment: It contains nothing. I want it for spacing.

Comment: It doesn't contain the links? That's the point of the `nav`, to contain the navigation (which in your case, are the links).

Comment: Is this better? I didn't read what you wrote. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `display: table-cell` on the elements inside `nav` works.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnmxm2h0/

Comment: Is it good coding practice to use a ul in a nav? I just though tables weren't supposed to be used for things like this.

Comment: @yuxuantim this is **`display:`** `table-cell`. You aren't actually creating a table here, just telling the browser to render the elements like a table.